# onblur functionality for TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What can I do to simulate or use the onblur functionality for a TR.

Here's my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/davomarti/4L859p5t/2/

```
<table>
  <tr id="view_1" onclick="showEditRow( '1' )"`enter code here`>
    <td>val1_1</td>
    <td>val1_2</td>
    <td>val1_3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="edit_1" style="display:none" onblur="showViewRow( '1' )">
    <td><input type="text" value="val1_1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="val1_2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="val1_3"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="view_2" onclick="showEditRow( '2' )">
    <td>val2_1</td>
    <td>val2_2</td>
    <td>val2_3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="edit_2" style="display:none" onblur="showViewRow( '2' )">
    <td><input type="text" value="val2_1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="val2_2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="val2_3"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>

function showEditRow( rowId ) {
    var editElemId = "#edit_" + rowId;
    var viewElemId = "#view_" + rowId;

    $(viewElemId).hide();
    $(editElemId).show();
}

function showViewRow(rowElem) {
    var editElemId = "#edit_" + rowId;
    var viewElemId = "#view_" + rowId;

    $(viewElemId).show();
    $(editElemId).hide();
}
```

I have coded onblur for the TR and I know that doesn't work for a TR.

I want to click on a row and get the edit boxes to replace the text, then when I click out of the row, I want the edit boxes to be replaced by the text TR.

Comment: You should add onblur event to the text inputs... use the jquery **"on"** function for that

Comment: Thanks rejnev.  I did that, but as soon as I click into a field to edit it, the onblur for the tr is fired.  Any suggestions on how to allow editting of the fields?

Comment: also in order for the onblur to work on rows, I had to add tabindex="-1" to the row and set focus on the visible row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help and for pointing me in the right direction.
I was able to solve the problem by looking at the blurring of the fields inside the tr.

http://jsfiddle.net/davomarti/4vzs33cm/

```
<table>
  <tr id="view_1" class="view">
    <td>val1_1</td>
    <td>val2_1</td>
    <td>val3_1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="edit_1" style="display:none" class="edit">
    <td><input class="inputCls" id="edit1_1" type="text" value="val1_1"/></td>
    <td><input class="inputCls" id="edit2_1" type="text" value="val1_2"/></td>
    <td><input class="inputCls" id="edit3_1" type="text" value="val1_3"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="view_2" class="view">
    <td>val1_2</td>
    <td>val2_2</td>
    <td>val3_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="edit_2" style="display:none" class="edit">
    <td><input class="inputCls" id="edit1_2" type="text" value="val1_2"/></td>
    <td><input class="inputCls" id="edit2_2" type="text" value="val2_2"/></td>
    <td><input class="inputCls" id="edit3_2" type="text" value="val3_2"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>

  $(document).ready(
    function()
    {
      var activeElem;

      $( ".view" ).on( "click", function() {
        var elemId = $(this).attr('id');
        var splitId = elemId.split( "_" );
        var id = splitId[1];

        var editElemId = "#edit_" + id;

        $( $(this) ).hide();
        $( editElemId ).show();
        $( editElemId ).find( "#edit2_" + id ).focus();
      });
      $( ".inputCls" ).on( "blur", function() {
        var elemId = $(this).attr('id');
        var splitId = elemId.split( "_" );
        var id = splitId[1];

        var thisTr = $(this).closest('tr');

        if( thisTr.find( "#" + activeElem.attr( "id" ) ).length === 0 ) {
          var viewTrId = "#view_" + id;

          thisTr.hide();
          $( viewTrId ).show();
        }
      });

      $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
        activeElem = $(e.target);
      });
    }
  );
```

Comment: Just for knowledge, It's better to start your jQuery variable's names with $ sign. like: **var $thisTr=$('selector')**

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to add an update button in the edit rows and on their **click** event hide the edit row:

The HTML:

```
<table class='table'>
  <tr>
    <th>item1</th>
    <th>item2</th>
    <th>item3</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row="1">
    <td>val1_1</td>
    <td>val1_2</td>
    <td>val1_3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row="2" style="display:none">
    <td><input type="text" value="val1_1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="val1_2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="val1_3"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="update"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row="3">
    <td>val2_1</td>
    <td>val2_2</td>
    <td>val2_3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row="4" style='display:none;'>
    <td><input type="text" value="val2_1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="val2_2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="val2_3"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="update"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table tr').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $this=$(this);
        if($this.data("row")%2==1)
        {
            showEditRow($this.data("row"));
        }
        else
        {
            showViewRow($this.data("row"));            
        }
    });
    $('.table tr input[type="button"]').click(function(){
        var tr=$(this).closest('tr');
        tr.hide();
        tr.prev().show();
    });
    $('.table tr input[type="text"]').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
});
 function showEditRow(row) {
     var tr = $('.table tr[data-row="'+row+'"]');
     tr.hide();
     tr.next("tr").show();
     tr.next('tr').find('input[type="text"]').first().focus();
 }

 function showViewRow(row) {
     var tr = $('.table tr[data-row="'+row+'"]');
     tr.hide();
     tr.prev("tr").show();
 }
```

[jsFiddleLink](http://jsfiddle.net/4L859p5t/11/)

Comment: Thanks rejnev.  It works, and I had similar functionality, though I like yours better.  The problem is that when I click into an input box, the edit row is replaced by the view row.  I want to be able to edit the fields and then click out of the row.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, get rid of the `onblur` on the `<tr>` tags.  Then, code something like this ...

```
$("tr").on('click', function() {
  // enable fields and disable text here
  // using something like $(this).find(".text").hide()
});
```

As stated in the comments, you probably should not connect this directly to the `<tr>` tag, but to a class attached to them so that you can limit down to just the elements you need to connect to.

You could also do it like this ...

```
$("body").on('click', "tr.pseudoClass", function() {
  // enable fields and disable text here
  // using something like $(this).find(".text").hide()
});
```

... which would allow for dynamic insertion of code without breaking.

Comment: that was a good suggestion.  I made the fix and it works great.  Instead of tr though, i had to assign a dummy class name to the rows that I want to operate on and select the rows by class name.